# IMAP_AirSeatMapService details

Tags: sabre

We want to retrieve seat availability from Sabre. However can not use **EnhancedSeatMapRQ** as its not activated. Documentation of a few services refer to **IMAP_AirSeatMapService**. But sabre dev studio does not reflect any documentation for this service. 
Questions I have are -
1. Is **IMAP_AirSeatMapService** available for use? If yes, would like to know the related resources (WSDL/XSDs)
2. What is the **alternative for EnhancedSeatMapRQ** to get seat availability during booking process?

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

EnhancedSeatMapRQ came as a replacement for IMAP service. 
If you do not have access to it, you should contact your Sabre account manager and request it.